# Не получается установить AndroidStudio Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio

Скачал с офф.сайт архив с адроид студией, распаковал ее в `/opt/` далее по инструкции нужно перейти  в `/opt/android-studio/bin/` и выполнить команду `studio.sh` в ответ получаю `studio.sh: command not found`

Пытался пропатчить ее в файле /etc/environment но этот файл доступен только для чтения.

Как можно исправить эту ситтуацию?

Comment: попробуйте ./studio.sh

Comment: @temq получилось, спасибо.

Comment: @temq nолько проблема теперь в том что  если так запустить студию - она запускается но если при этом закрыть консоль  из которой она запускалась  то студия тоже закроется,  как это можно исправить

Comment: Это особенность запуска приложений через консоль - закрываете консоль, закрывается приложение. Когда ```Android Studio``` запущена, нажать правой кнопкой на ярлык в панели и закрепить его там, но тогда, лично у меня, сломались обновления студии. Т.е. после нажатия "обновить" студия закрывалась и не запускалась. Работать обновления начинали только после того, как я запускал студию через консоль

Comment: Чтобы консоль не мешала, создайте лаунчер или добавьте студию в меню.